# How to enable http conncetion for particular action in ASP.NET Core MVC?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm developing an ASP.NET Core 2.1 MVC application. I use basic https enforcement:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddHttpsRedirection(options =>
    {
        options.HttpsPort = 443;
    });
}
```

I need to handle api requests from third party, which are unfortunately made with simple http and don't handle 307 redirection to https. I'm looking for a simple way to enable those requests on chosen action/controller.

Please advice.

Comment: Try to change Redirect Status code to 200 before : options.RedirectStatusCode = 200

Comment: Also, it's not a bad idea to read this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.builder.httpspolicybuilderextensions.usehttpsredirection?view=aspnetcore-3.1